# ggplot overlay plot error, no layers in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay two variables on a same figure with ggplot2, so I use melt to get the data in the correct format and then use the following:

```
Locations <- c("USA","UK","Spain")
vals_1 <- c(44,6,76)
vals_2 <- c(0.2,0.9,4.1)

dat <- data.frame(Locs = Locations,
                  method_1 = vals_1,
                  method_2 = vals_2)
dat2 <- melt(dat,id = "Locs")

ggplot(data = dat2,
       aes(x = Locs, y = value, colour = variable))
```

but this generates an error. Why does it state that there are no layers?

Is this to do with the class of dat2[,1] and dat2[,2] being a factor? If so, what should it be changed to? I would like the graph to show the string in dat2[,1] on the xaxis and both the variables shown in the plot. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Amend:

After adding

geom_line()

to get

```
ggplot(data = dat2,
       aes(x = Locs, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

I receive the following error
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: You haven't added any geom_ to your plot, for example, +geom_bar()

Comment: thanks, please see amended post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell `ggplot()` which points to connect by lines. This is done by adding `group=variable` inside the `aes()`.

```
ggplot(data = dat2,
       aes(x = Locs, y = value, colour = variable,group=variable)) +
  geom_line()
```